# .NET Core 2 build is not working in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-3.1

All,

I have a build server that has .NET Core 2.2.110 installed in it. For my new application, I need .NET Core 3.1. So I've installed .NET Core 3.1 in addition to .NET Core 2.2.110.

When I hit dotnet --version I get **3.1**

The build is working fine when building applications developed in .NET Core 3.1 but it's failing for the below framework applications and giving me the following error

**The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found**

I have both 2.1 as well as 3.1 on my build machine, technically applications developed by 3.1 should use .NET Core 3.1 f/w, and apps developed by 2.2.110 should use .NET Core 2.2.110.

Also, any upgraded framework should also support previous versioned apps but in my case, it's failing.

Please help me

Comment: try the ```dotnet add package MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets --version 14.0.0.3 ``` on the build server

Comment: It sounds like you need to download and install the [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1) on your server.

Comment: May I know which version of visual studio you are using?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron : I don't have any VS installed instead I've installed .NET Core 3.1 and 2.2 on build machines. But 2.2 apps are not getting compiled though I've it installed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can specify the target platform in each project.

Add the line :
`<PropertyGroup><TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>/PropertyGroup>` in you .csproj file to compile with .Net 3.1 or `netcoreapp2.0` for .Net 2